# android to show alert dialog from non-UI or Non activity class

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

Hi Android programmers,

This question is previously asked. But there is no answer. So i need solution for that. Actually i am trying to display alert box of `Mainactivity.java` calling from `test.java`(Non-activity).

***Thats working fine if their is no UI coding. if that code is dependent with UI means its throw errors.***

Activity class :

```
public class Mainactivity extends Activity
{
    public void message()
    {
        Log.i("Success : Call from non-UI & non activity class");//Upto this line working if i called message() function from other non-activity class
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
        {
             switch (which)
             {
                //Code
            }
         }
     };
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     builder.setTitle("FMS Status Message :- ");
     builder.setMessage(msg)
     .setPositiveButton("OK",dialogClickListener).show();

    }
}
```

Non-Activity class :

```
public class test extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    Mainactvity in = new Mainactvity();   

    @Override   
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
       in.message();
    }
}
```

If it is resolved then my main objective of my project will be completed. Please any one of you help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it throws errors- Can you please post the error?

Comment: Why you do't think of passing Context and Activity from your Mainactvity  to class test.And also the code you are showing is Bad Programming Practice for Android,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of All, Bad Programming Practice for Android,

```
Mainactvity in = new Mainactvity();
```

You can not make a Constructor of Activity class.

And second, You are trying to display UI elements in Dialog which has not reference of Activity, in `BroadcastReceiver`.  Use **Context** of Activity (If it concern with UI) or Application for displaying Dialog in BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. Is there possibility to display alert box in test class..?

Comment: I tried this, but its not working : Context mContext = getApplicationContext(); final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); alert.setTitle("Got message, From: " + to); alert.setCancelable(true); alert.show(); Note test class is not an activity. Please reply me.

Comment: Actually, I need to display an alert box in test(Non-activity) class. Thats it..!

Comment: You can not make a `AlertDialog` in `BroadcastReceiver`. You have to maintain a callback mechanism with  your `Activity` and `BroadcastReceiver`. Once you get appropriate action in broadcast receiver which trigger your Activity and from Activity you can call AlertDialog method. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844031/alertdialog-from-within-broadcastreceiver-can-it-be-done

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Constructor`, where you can get Activity. Like this -

```
Activity activity;
public test (Activity activity){
         this.activity = activity;
}
```

Now, use this `activity` as argument -

`AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);`

Because dialog can't be shown using just a `context`. You need to provide an `Activity` for that.

I answered one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26382502/609782)

Comment: This doesn't work. The Dialog is not created with the passed activity, no error but no dialog as well.

Comment: You may ask a new question and post your code, so that I can see it.

Comment: I get this to say it not work, good idea though:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference